# $F(x) = \int_0^x \sin{((x+t)^s)} dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $F(x) = \int_0^x \sin{((x+t)^s)} dt$ , how can i find the derivative with respect to $x$.

First i tried to use the fundamental theorem of calculus  that asserts that $$\text{if } F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt \text{ then } \frac{dF}{dx} = f(x)$$ then using my function $F(x)$ and setting $g(x) = \sin{x}$ and $h(x) = (x+t)^s$ then $F(x) = g(h(x))$ so using chai rule i get that $F´(x) = g(h(x)) h´(x)$ then $$F´(x) = \sin{((x+x)^s)} [s(x+t)^{s-1}]$$ is that correct ? , please some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have differentiated incorrectly. Check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

For the current problem, it is easier to handle it by using the substitution $x+t=y$ i.e
$$\int_{x}^{2x}\sin(y^s)\,dy$$
Differentiate wrt $x$ to obtain:
$$\boxed{2\sin((2x)^s)-\sin(x^s)}$$

Comment: why you get the limits of integration $x$ and $2x$ ?

Comment: @Knight: Do you mean to ask that why did I go by the substitution method?

Comment: well you put $x+t=y$ then you got $\sin(y^s) dy$ but why you got $\int_x^{2x}$ ,i.e, why you got $x$ and $2x$ ?

Comment: For example if i have a similar $F(x) = \int_0^x e^{(x+t)^8} dt$ then i put  $x+t=y$ , i.e, $\int_{x}^{2x}e^{(y^8)}\,dy$
Differentiating with respect to $x$ we get: ${2e^{((2y)^8)}-e^{(y^8)}}$

Comment: @Knight: If $t=0$, then $y=x$ and if $t=x$, $y=2x$, hence the limits are $x$ and $2x$. Does this answer your question?